# Intermittent denial of commenting privilege

Tags: bug

In the last week I've gotten this occasionally

[image]

I re-try and it eventually works.

Maybe it's getting all judgmental on me :)

Comment: That happens to me when my WiFi connection is getting flaky and I think I look like I'm not logged in to SE any more. Usually though when I see that, SE has decided to log me out, and I can't post until I go through logging in again. But for you, it "eventually works" without having to log in again? (fyi I don't use the FB or Google kind of log in, just plain vanilla user/password)

Comment: Yes, I don't have to log in again.  And I also use a plain vanilla login.  Thanks for sharing your experience though - I had never seen this before.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Like uhoh, said I've experienced this with intermittent connectivity issues before. And I don't always have to log in again.

Comment: fyi the `bug` tag attracts people who want to add the `by-design` tag as soon as possible in order to say "there are no bugs in SE". I usually avoid that tag at first, until I'm fairly sure it really is a not-easily-dismissed bug that isn't `by-design`

Comment: Interesting! Nothing else is complaining about connections.  But sounds like that is it.

Comment: This might be better suited on the super-meta since it deals with a bug in the SE software itself and might gain more visibility there.